# Error when reading a table has more than 100 fields_pyodbc

Tags: python, linux, pyodbc

I get a problem when running

```
cursor.execute("select * from ObjTransaction_20121115;")
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The table has more than 100 fields, so after executing fetchone, i got an error "bus error" . If it lauch on the table that has several fields, there is no problem.

So can you suggest me how to solve that problem ? maybe this is a memrory error.

In my system, there are a lot of such tables.

My pyodbc is pyodbc-3.0.2-1.x86_64 on Opensuse 12.2 64b

Comment: What happens if you select a subset of the columns, instead of `*`?

Comment: if you need just one row, use `LIMIT` in your query. fetchone doesn't make sure the query only returns one result, it just throws away the rest of the results except the first.

Comment: Martjin: there is no problem if select only a subset, but what i want is all of those fields inside the table

Comment: Mata: above is just an example, i can use fetchall() but at lease there is an error when using fetchone().  

And when i tried  

    cursor.execute("select * from ObjTransaction_20121115 LIMIT 2;")

I get error too, syntax error.

Comment: @SieuTruc What database platform?

Comment: @beargle: my database i want to read is SQL Server 2000, I think it's a memory error, it cannot store a lot of data in array

Comment: @SieuTruc The error as you've described it above is not a memory error. Use the `SELECT TOP...` syntax in T-SQL to limit rows returned. `LIMIT` is not valid T-SQL.

Comment: @beargle: i even used row = cursor.fetchone() , just only 1 row, but the erros also occured, is it not enough heap size for storing data ?

Comment: @SieuTruc Please edit the post with code used in your most recent attempt.

Comment: I'm also getting this, and it seems to be related for me to specific columns, not specifically about the amount of data coming back. I think this is the correct bug report: https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/issues/detail?id=300